# Writing special characters (α, β) in bash to an output file - not encoding correctly

Tags: awk, encoding

I'm attempting to modify an existing file (input.csv) using the awk command in the OSX terminal and then writing the output to a file (output.csv).

The command I have works for the text changes I need and displays the output correctly in the terminal (including correct special characters):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2) }}1' input.csv
```

I then attempt to write this output to a file by piping it to the tee command:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2) }}1' input.csv | tee output.csv
```

I find the that the special characters in the file are now corrupted, e.g. "α-Synuclein"
becomes "Œ±-synuclein". I believe this is to do with the encoding but am unsure how to specify which to use or where to change it.

I've noticed the by running the command `file input.txt` the encoding listed is:

> "UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with very long lines, with CRLF line
> terminators"

When I run `file output.txt` on the output file I get:

> "Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF, LF line
> terminators"

I think this means I should be encoding the output file as UTF-8... Can anyone suggest a way to fix this so that I can write these characters to my output file without them becoming corrupted?

Comment: Maybe take a look at [google "awk UTF-8 Unicode"](https://www.google.com/search?q=awk+%22UTF-8+Unicode%22) results?

Comment: It sounds like your default locale assumes a different encoding than UTF-8.  You could try something like `( export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8; awk ... | tee file )`.  The specific locale name you need to use might vary.  Do not omit the parentheses, which cause the command to be run in a subshell, unless you want the locale change to be persistent in the shell from which you run that.

Comment: _Greek Small Letter Alpha_ `α` is UTF-8 byte sequence  `0xCE`,`0xB1`. It appears as `Œ±` (_Latin Capital Ligature Oe_ and _Plus-Minus Sign_) if interpreted in `'mac_roman'` encoding. Classic [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case.

Comment: Using the above ( export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8; awk ... | tee file ) solution works perfectly. Thanks for the help